# The mutable variable 'index' is used in an invalid way in seq {}?

Tags: f#

In the following code, the compiler gets error on `index <- index + 1` with error

> Error 3   The mutable variable 'index' is used in an invalid way. Mutable variables cannot be captured by closures. Consider eliminating this use of mutation or using a heap-allocated mutable reference cell via 'ref' and '!'. d:\Users....\Program.fs    11  22  ConsoleApplication2

However, it has been defined as mutable?

```
let rec iterateTupleMemberTypes (tupleArgTypes: System.Type[]) (columnNames: string[]) startingIndex = 
    seq {
        let mutable index = startingIndex
        for t in tupleArgTypes do
            match t.IsGenericType with
            | true -> iterateTupleMemberTypes (t.GetGenericArguments()) columnNames index |> ignore
            | false ->
                printfn "Name: %s Type: %A" (columnNames.[index]) t
                index <- index + 1
                yield (columnNames.[index]), t
    } |> Map.ofSeq

let myFile = CsvProvider<"""d:\temp\sample.txt""">.GetSample()
let firstRow = myFile.Rows |> Seq.head
let tupleType = firstRow.GetType()
let tupleArgTypes = tupleType.GetGenericArguments()
let m = iterateTupleMemberTypes tupleArgTypes myFile.Headers.Value 0
```

Comment: no it is **not** - because you overwrite the mutable value `index` again with a inmutable value equal to 0 in the very next line `let index = 0`

Comment: what are you trying to do with this?

Comment: Sorry forgot to clear the debug line. I've revised the question.

Comment: I've trying to get the type information of the type provider variable of CSV files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An idiomatic version of this might look like the following:

```
#r @"..\packages\FSharp.Data.2.2.2\lib\net40\FSharp.Data.dll"

open FSharp.Data
open System

type SampleCsv = CsvProvider<"Sample.csv">

let sample = SampleCsv.GetSample()

let rec collectLeaves (typeTree : Type) =
    seq {
        match typeTree.IsGenericType with
        | false -> yield typeTree.Name
        | true -> yield! typeTree.GetGenericArguments() |> Seq.collect collectLeaves
    }

let columnTypes = (sample.Rows |> Seq.head).GetType() |> collectLeaves

let columnDefinitions = columnTypes |> Seq.zip sample.Headers.Value |> Map.ofSeq

let getDefinitions (sample : SampleCsv) = (sample.Rows |> Seq.head).GetType() |> collectLeaves |> Seq.zip sample.Headers.Value |> Map.ofSeq
```

Personally, I wouldn't be concerned too much about the performance of `Map` vs `Dictionary` (and rather have the immutable `Map`) unless there are hundreds of columns.

Comment: I'm trying to wrap the last to rows in a function `let getDefinitions sample = (sample.Rows |> Seq.head).GetType() |> collectLeaves |> Seq.zip sample.Headers.Value |> Map.ofSeq`. However, it requires the parameter `sample` having type annotation. How to write the type annotation of sample?

Comment: The type of sample is `CsvProvider<"Sample.csv">`, after all, that's what type providers are about. `GetSample` returns a sample of such a type, i.e. the type itself. So the only way (I can think of) to write this is ```let getDefinitions (sample : CsvProvider<"Sample.csv">) = (sample.Rows |> Seq.head).GetType() |> collectLeaves |> Seq.zip sample.Headers.Value |> Map.ofSeq``` which could be written like shown in the edited answer.

Comment: Great. Just realize that the `CsvProvider` accepts a constant value as type  variable. Is it similar to the ones in Haskell or C++ template which accept value?

Answer (score 1):

The statement after it, `let index = 0`, shadows your definition of mutable variable `index`. Also, to make mutables work in sequences, you need refs. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233186.aspx

Comment: `refs` works. Thanks. BTW, I read that dict is much faster than map for looking up. However, there is not `Dict.ofSeq`?

Comment: but there is an extension method on `IEnumerable` (`System.Linq`)

Comment: @dc7a9163d9 : The `dict` function is what you're after!

Comment: @ildjarn Thanks. It works. Hovering the mouse on the `m` shows `IDictionary`. However, `printfn "%A" m` shows `seq
  [[A, System.Int32]; [B, System.DateTime]; [C, System.String];
   [D, System.Decimal]; ...]`

Answer (score 0):

Suggested by @Ming-Tang, I changed the mutable variable to `ref` and it works now. However, is it a way not to use mutable/ref variable at all?

```
let rec iterateTupleMemberTypes (tupleArgTypes: System.Type[]) (columnNames: string[]) startingIndex = 
    seq {
        let index = ref startingIndex
        for t in tupleArgTypes do
            match t.IsGenericType with
            | true ->
                yield! iterateTupleMemberTypes (t.GetGenericArguments()) columnNames !index
            | false ->
                printfn "Name: %s Type: %A" (columnNames.[!index]) t
                yield (columnNames.[!index]), t
                index := !index + 1
    } |> dict

let myFile = CsvProvider<"""d:\temp\sample.txt""">.GetSample()
let firstRow = myFile.Rows |> Seq.head
let tupleType = firstRow.GetType()
let tupleArgTypes = tupleType.GetGenericArguments()
let m = iterateTupleMemberTypes tupleArgTypes myFile.Headers.Value 0
```

Comment: Maybe Seq.take, Seq.skip and Seq.truncate will help you

Comment: Note that `iterateTupleMemberTypes` does not work as expected when there are more than 8 columns as you are not taking into account the result of the recursive call.

Comment: Generally speaking, mutable variables + for loops can be replaced with recursive functions + parameter like this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9560685/901059